# Functions in R - using eval() and parse() to plot expressions in rgl

Tags: r, function, eval, readline, rgl

I am very new to R. I am trying to create a function where the user is able to input expressions into arguments.  These inputs are then used in plot3d through the rgl package.  The function I have so far is :

```
flight_sim <- function(xval, yval, zval)
{
# Evaluate arguments and convert them into expressions 
eval(parse(text = zval))
z <- data.frame(zval)
eval(parse(text = xval))
x <- data.frame(xval)
eval(parse(text = yval))
y <- data.frame(yval)
flight_path <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
}
```

I have a readline() and switch() command :

```
cat('Select the flight path you wish to plot from the list below : 
1. Helix
2. Conical
3. Spherical
4. Define your own flight path...')

userplot <- readline('Enter number here : ') # Allow user to enter choice from above

switch(userplot,"1"=flight_sim( sin(z), 1-cos(z), seq(0,20, pi/32) ),
                "2"=flight_sim( z*cos(6*z), z*sin(6*z), seq(0,10, pi/64) ),
                "3"=flight_sim( sin(z)*cos(20*z), sin(z)*sin(20*z), seq(0,pi,pi/399)), 
                "4"=custom())
```

Where custom() just prompts the user via readline() to enter x, y and z values, which is then followed by eval() and parse() and it works fine.

The problem I've been having is that x and y need to be functions of z, and this causes an error :

```
Error in parse(text = xval) : object 'z' not found
```

I thought by making the flight_sim function evaluate the zval argument first that it would fix it, however as I'm new to R I'm just getting more and more lost.

I hope what I have explained here makes some sense.  I appreciate any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is being passed as text in your example so using `parse()` doesn't seem necessary. If you want to delay evaulation, the best way would be to use `substitute` to grab the parameters as promises and then evaluate them in the context of your `fliht_sim` function. Here's what that would look like

```
flight_sim <- function(xval, yval, zval) {
    z <- eval(substitute(zval))
    x <- eval(substitute(xval))
    y <- eval(substitute(yval))
    data.frame(x,y,z)
}


userplot="2"

x <- switch(userplot,"1"=flight_sim( sin(z), 1-cos(z), seq(0,20, pi/32) ),
                "2"=flight_sim( z*cos(6*z), z*sin(6*z), seq(0,10, pi/64) ),
                "3"=flight_sim( sin(z)*cos(20*z), sin(z)*sin(20*z), seq(0,pi,pi/399)), 
                "4"=custom())
head(x)
#            x          y          z
# 1 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
# 2 0.04697370 0.01424932 0.04908739
# 3 0.08162934 0.05454298 0.09817477
# 4 0.09342212 0.11383519 0.14726216
# 5 0.07513972 0.18140332 0.19634954
# 6 0.02405703 0.24425508 0.24543693
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I changed parse() to substitute() and everything started working a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, it seems like you'd need to redefine your function. To the best of my knowledge, you can't define an argument in the function definition as a function of another argument. You'd need to do that inside the body of the function. So you'd want something like this:

```
flight_sim <- function(userplot) {
  if (userplot == "1") {
    z <- seq(0, 20, pi / 32)
    x <- sin(z)
    y <- 1 - cos(z)
  } else if (userplot == "2") {
    z <- seq(0, 10, pi / 64)
    x <- z * cos(6 * z)
    y <- z * sin(6 * z)
  } else if (userplot == "3") {
    z <- seq(0, pi, pi / 399)
    x <- sin(z) * cos(20 * z)
    y <- sin(z) * sin(20 * z)
  } else if (userplot == "4") {
    x <- readline("Please enter a function for the x-value: ")
    y <- readline("Please enter a function for the y-value: ")
    z <- readline("Please enter a function for the z-value: ")
    eval(parse(text = z)) # have to evaluate z first since x and y are functions of z
    eval(parse(text = x))
    eval(parse(text = y))
  } else {
    valid_response <- FALSE
    while (!valid_response) {
      userplot <- readline("Please enter a valid response (1-4): ")
      if (userplot %in% 1:4) {
        valid_response <- TRUE
        flight_sim(userplot)
      }
    }
  }
  dat <- data.frame(x, y, z)
  return(dat)
}

cat('Select the flight path you wish to plot from the list below : 
1. Helix
    2. Conical
    3. Spherical
    4. Define your own flight path...')

userplot <- readline('Enter number here : ') # Allow user to enter choice from above

dat <- flight_sim(userplot)

head(dat)
                     x                    y                    z
1 0.000000000000000000 0.000000000000000000 0.000000000000000000
2 0.046973698885313400 0.014249315773629733 0.049087385212340517
3 0.081629338302900922 0.054542980081485989 0.098174770424681035
4 0.093422122547587999 0.113835185692147969 0.147262155637021552
5 0.075139716235543288 0.181403322008714424 0.196349540849362070
6 0.024057025623845932 0.244255080177979672 0.245436926061702587
```

In the code above, I've also included one last `else` statement to catch inappropriate responses from your users. If they enter a choice that could break your code, it will now catch that and ask them to reenter their response.